# Can i get the data which is not belong to form with wordpress custom shortcode?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I am having an issue with my custom shortcode. Right now I have a custom shortcode name as [inquiry] which pop up the form and send the data I added the shortcode in the 4 products which added in page content as grid format what I want to do if any user clicks on inquiry button (which come from custom shortcode). I want to also name of the product in the mail.

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2430996/e3e7e2101e9500e0a292327b7a2be9ea
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2431001/e5dfc397285267c20953e5e034ca852b

The name of the product in  tag and form is outside of that.

Is there any trick I can do that name of the product can store as PHP variable or I need to add parameter WordPress shortcode?

Thanks